# regex error when using cpp11 regex

Tags: regex, c++11

I was trying to verify the complexity of password using `std::regex`, and get some examples like:

`^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,20}$`

I translate it into
`regex pwd_regex=regex(string("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,20}$"));`

But get an exception of `regex_error` with error code 4 at runtime (gcc 4.8.5).

What's wrong? I try other examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621491/password-validator-without-special-characters) , but also failed.

Comment: What [constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/error_type) does error code 4 represent?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_error for how to translate the error code to a meaningful message.

Comment: @Barmar The output is "regex_error". I've tried this in online compiler without error . So maybe there is something wrong with my local compiler environment.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921932/understanding-c-regex-by-a-simple-example/30922295) is different than what you used, and looks like this:

```
std::string str("password");
std::regex r("^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\\d)[A-Za-z\\d]{8,20}$");
std::smatch m;
std::regex_search(str, m, r);
```

Comment: But is there any difference? There is an implicit type conversion in your example.

Comment: @bigxiao I'm not a C++ person, but when I searched for `std::regex` I found the linked question, whose syntax looks different.  If this doesn't help the OP I'm happy to delete it.

Comment: Do you really need to double the backslashes inside a raw string?

Comment: @Barmar Are you stack-stalking me bro?